# Se solicita adjetivo para decir "que pica"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, españa, adjetivos, vocabulario-médico

Ayer viendo *Cómo entrenar a tu dragón 2* el prota, al principio de la peli, pregunta a su dragón como llamar a una nueva tierra que han encontrado. El dragón está frotándose bajo el ala con el morro y el prota dice algo así como "vale, 'sobaco picajoso'".

En la versión original dicen "itchy armpit", así que entiendo que usan *picajoso* como adjetivo para decir "que pica" (en el sentido de querer rascarte). Me pareció genial... hasta que vi la definición en el DLE:

> **[picajoso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsUEtgu)**
>
> 1. adj. Que fácilmente se pica o da por ofendido. U. t. c. s.

Horror, según el DLE *picajoso* hace referencia a *picarse* pero no a *picar*. Con lo que me había gustado la palabra... Pues nada, pregunto: ¿hay algún otro adjetivo que se pueda usar con el mismo significado? ¿O tal vez ha tenido *picajoso* en el pasado la acepción que yo esperaba? ¿O sí que se usa con esa acepción de *picar* solo que el DLE no la recoge?

Comment: @Berenguela gracias, "picajón" ha sido propuesta ya por ukemi en su respuesta.

Comment: No lo recoge la RAE, pero los niños suelen decir "¡eres un picota!", un poco al igual que "eres un chivota" (en lugar de chivato).

Comment: @FGSUZ el diccionario de americanismos sí lo recoge: [picota](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=picota) *`Ch. Referido a persona,`* `que se molesta o enfada rápidamente o envidia cuanto ocurre a su alrededor. `

Comment: Para mi 'sobaco picajoso' suena bien y no es una de aquellas cosas que requieren precisión lexical.  Lo tomaría como una licencia poética... o algo parecido.

Answer (score 5):

De primeras se me ha ocurrido [**irritante**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M9ocUH9):

> **irritante**
>   1. adj. Que irrita.

Aunque no es muy habitual identificar la sensación de irritación con la de picor.

Entonces, tirando un poco de DIRAE, me he ido a [**urticante**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bAdFbsF) (que en realidad era la primera palabra que estaba buscando pero no me salía):

> **urticante**
>   Del lat. mediev. *urticans*, -*antis*, part. pres. act. de *urticare* 'producir un picor intenso', y este der. del lat. *urtīca* 'ortiga'.
>
> 1. adj. Que produce comezón (|| picazón) semejante a las picaduras de ortiga.

Ahora bien, la puntilla de "semejante a las picaduras de ortiga" fastidia un poco el plan...

Quizá para el uso que quieres darle quedaría mejor "sobaco [**sarnoso**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XJqkWlI)", por aquello de que la sarna produce picor:

> **sarnoso, sa**
>   1. adj. Que tiene **sarna**. U. t. c. s.
>
> > **sarna**
> >     1. f. Afección cutánea contagiosa provocada por un ácaro o arador, que excava túneles bajo la piel, produciendo enrojecimiento, tumefacción y un intenso **prurito**.
> >
> > > **prurito**
> > >       2. m. Med. Comezón, picazón.

Lo gramaticalmente lógico sería quizá usar [picante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SscF91J), pero el término está tan asociado a la comida que no tiene sentido ninguno usarlo en este contexto. Además, la acepción de [**picar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsuIXMH) a la que te refieres es la 29:

> **picar**
>   29. intr. Dicho de una parte del cuerpo de alguien: Hacerle experimentar picor. *Me pica la garganta*.

En esta forma es un verbo intransitivo, y dudo mucho que sea la acepción a la que se refiere el DLE cuando define "picante" como algo "que pica" y no como algo "que *te* pica" (por ejemplo).
De hecho, los diccionarios en línea más conocidos especifican "que pica *en el paladar*": véase [aquí](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/picante), [aquí](https://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/picante), [aquí](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/picante), o [aquí](http://espasa.planetasaber.com/encyclopedia/default.asp?idreg=108955&ruta=Buscador) (gracias, [blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14069/blonfu), por [indicármelo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48452155#48452155)).

Answer (score 4):

Qué tal "urticante"?

> [urticante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bAdFbsF)
>
> 1. adj. Que produce comezón semejante a las picaduras de ortiga.

y [comezón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9vmTdzJ) es a su vez

> 1. f. **Picazón** que se padece en alguna parte del cuerpo o en todo él.

y recordar que [urticaria](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bAfzEVl) es una

> Enfermedad eruptiva de la piel, cuyo síntoma más notable es una comezón parecida a la que producen las picaduras de la ortiga.

Answer (score 2):

> [**picante**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=picante)
> <sub>De *picar* y *-nte.*</sub>
>
> 1. adj. Que pica.

Para el otro sentido (de picar**se**) ademas de picajoso hay [picajón](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=picaj%C3%B3n).

Comment: Estoy tan acostumbrado a su uso para la comida picante que no me lo imaginaba para usarlo como picor de rascarse. ¿Tienes ejemplos de uso en ese sentido?

Comment: @Charlie Hmm, hay estos: [*Delmar's English/Spanish Pocket Dictionary for Health Professionals*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JrAEHX_l6NkC&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=picante+itchy); [*International Medical Interpreters Association: Spanish Pain Description Glossary*](http://www.imiaweb.org/uploads/docs/Pain_Description_Glossary_Spanish.pdf): `Prickly, pricking, itchy - Picar/que pica, punzante, picante` pero ese uso no parece muy difundido.

Answer (score 2):

O **pruriginoso**, que habitualmente se utiliza para indicar **que escuece o que causa picor** [(**ejemplo**)](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/pruriginoso), aunque estríctamente el [**DLE**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UVep9U3) lo define

> Del lat. *pruriginōsus*.
>   1. adj. Med. De la naturaleza del prurigo.
>   2. adj. Med. Que produce prurigo.

y siendo [**prurigo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UVjPtJL)

> Del lat. *prurīgo* 'picor, comezón'.
>   1. m. Med. Afección cutánea, caracterizada por pápulas cubiertas frecuentemente de costras negruzcas debidas a excoriaciones producidas por rascarse.

Comment: "Las palabras **prurigo** y **pruriginoso** tienen la misma etimología en el vocablo prurito, si bien en la práctica médica es necesario hacer alguna distinción. El prurito o comezón [...] El adjetivo derivado de prurito es **pruriginoso** y, por tanto, se aplica a cualquier situación en la que aparezca este síntoma [...] **Prurigo** o **prúrigo**, que ambas formas son válidas, es una entidad patológica independiente constituida por la aparición de lesiones dermatológicas [...]" [Fuente](https://medicablogs.diariomedico.com/laboratorio/2007/01/10/dudas-razonables-prurigo-y-pruriginoso/)

Comment: "Es curioso cómo la palabra **prurito**, ha pasado de la terminología médica al habla popular con el significado de “afán con que se persigue hacer una cosa de la manera más completa o más perfecta posible, generalmente sólo por virtuosismo o para satisfacer el amor propio”. Así, se le ha despojado de su valor negativo, de sensación molesta, para otorgarle otro positivo, de encomio de la voluntad." (misma fuente que el anterior comentario)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que "picajoso" no funciona muy bien porque se va a entender más bien *quisquilloso,* o *especial* (utilizado sarcásticamente).

No me gustan mucho las palabras ya propuestas, ya que son un tanto formales, por lo que propongo

> Axila sarnosa

[Sarna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XJj4Yzn): "Afección cutánea contagiosa provocada por un ácaro o arador, que excava túneles bajo la piel, produciendo enrojecimiento, tumefacción y un intenso prurito."

"Sarnosa" no equivale exactamente a "itchy," pero creo que funciona bien porque si la axila es sarnosa, entonces pica.  Además, se oye como insulto en varios países.  Me parece que las películas y programas modernos incluyen muchos insultos, algunas veces usados como expresiones de cariño.

Answer (score -1):

Qué tal "cáustico"?

> [cáustico, ca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=80dUZXa)
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que quema y destruye los tejidos animales.
> 2. adj. Mordaz o agresivo en lo que dice.

Puedes tener el sentido de que "pica" o "irrita" a nivel físico o figurado (Mordaz, incisivo, hiriente).

Comment: La palabra en sí me gusta pero creo que no sería aplicable en este contexto, ¿no? Normalmente cuando se dice que algo o alguien es cáustico es porque el daño lo produce en un tercero, produce esa quemazón o irritación en otra persona o material. Entiendo que sobaco cáustico se aplicaria si estuviera causando daño en el jinete pero es la propia montura la que siente la comezón.